Mounting Alchemy CMS with Existing Rails App
I have a question similar to this one but the solution does not work.
Basically, I have an existing Rails application that uses several bespoke routes for the /admin space (namely, these are an effect of Active Admin), and I need to integrate a CMS for a new space that would fall under '/blog' or '/cms.' I've installed Alchemy, and when I mount it to root at the top of the routes file, I get the engine just fine, but when I try to mount it under a scope, I get a missing route error.
Basically, I'm trying to get something like this video where there is the active admin login and a separate section for the pages managed by Alchemy.
# routes.rb


Rails.application.routes.draw do

# Homepage
root to: 'pages#home'

...

# Active admin
ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config

devise_scope :admin_user do
  get "/admin/auth/google/callback", to: "admin_user_omniauth_callbacks#google"
end
get "/admin/queues/:id", to: 'admin/queues#show', as: 'admin_que_job'

...

mount Alchemy::Engine => '/cms'

end

I add the default scope:
# config/alchemy.rb

Alchemy::Engine.routes.default_scope = { path: '/cms' }

Alchemy.user_class_name = 'AdminUser'
Alchemy.login_path = '/admin/login'
Alchemy.logout_path = '/admin/logout'


Adding the url_prefix:
# config/alchemy/config.yml
...
url_prefix: '/cms'
...

Edit: I'll also include the rails routes output for this area:
Routes for Alchemy::Engine:
                          root GET    /cms(.:format)                                        pages#index
                               GET    /cms/sitemap.xml(.:format)                            pages#sitemap {:format=>/xml/}
                         admin GET    /cms/admin(.:format)                                  redirect(301, admin/dashboard)
               admin_dashboard GET    /cms/admin/dashboard(.:format)                        admin/dashboard#index
                dashboard_info GET    /cms/admin/dashboard/info(.:format)                   admin/dashboard#info

Update:
When I try to navigate to: /cms/admin
Error:
Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/cms/admin"

In the routes, it shows:
admin_path  GET     /cms/admin(.:format)    

redirect(301, admin/dashboard)

Adding a route, such as 'homepage' and a corresponding page_layouts.yml descriptor doesn't resolve to /cms/admin/homepage.

Please add the details on the missing routes error

Updated above. It's basically the same. No route matches.
